# Can't merge cells in GridControl in MultiColumnComboBox control of SyncFusion

Tags: syncfusion

We are using a MultiColumnComboBox control and we would like to customize the grid to merge columns (see above screenshot). However, using the below code does not seem to work. The QueryCanMergeCells callback does not appear to even get called.

var grid = this.multiColumnComboBox1.ListBox.Grid; // Grid is SyncFusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.GridControl type

grid.QueryCellInfo += Grid_QueryCellInfo;

// Set MergeCells direction for the GridControl.
grid.TableStyle.MergeCell = GridMergeCellDirection.ColumnsInRow; // | GridMergeCellDirection.RowsInColumn;

// Set merge cells behavior for the Grid.
grid.Model.Options.MergeCellsMode = GridMergeCellsMode.OnDemandCalculation | GridMergeCellsMode.MergeColumnsInRow;

grid.Model.Options.MergeCellsLayout = GridMergeCellsLayout.Grid;

grid.QueryCanMergeCells += new GridQueryCanMergeCellsEventHandler(Grid_QueryCanMergeCells);

https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/146073/can39t-merge-cells-in-gridcontrol-of-multicolumncombobox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the provided sample, the MergeCell option of the cells were not updated for the each cells. In order to overcome this scenario, the QueryCellInfo event can be used to set the MergeCell style for each cells. Please make use of the below code,

Code example

```
private void Grid_QueryCellInfo(object sender, GridQueryCellInfoEventArgs e) 
{ 
    //To set the merge cell for each cell. 
    e.Style.MergeCell = GridMergeCellDirection.ColumnsInRow; 
    if (e.ColIndex == 1 && e.RowIndex > 1) 
    { 
        //To change the cell type as CheckBox 
        e.Style.CheckBoxOptions = new GridCheckBoxCellInfo("true", "false", "", true); 
        e.Style.CellType = GridCellTypeName.CheckBox; 
    } 
}
```